# How to pass several values in a single post parameter in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, post

I'm using the [chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) UI library to select multiple values for a post param named 'tables'. In the Chrome network console I can check that is working how I expected:

```
Form data
checkin:2012-06-15 16:00:00
checkout:2012-06-15 17:00:00
tables:14
tables:15
tables:16
customer:28
```

But when I try to recover this tables info in the controller

```
var_dump($this->input->post('tables'));
```

I only got the last value for the param:

```
string(2) "16"
```

I also try `var_dump($_POST['tables']);` when the same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try calling it `tables[]` instead of `tables`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm curious about where you found it, because I was looking in the oficial docs and I found nothing there.

Comment: Didn't find it anywhere - nothing to do with chosen or CodeIgniter, actually - I've just had enough experience with PHP over HTTP to know that stood a chance of being the problem.

Comment: because "tables" has multiple values, we can assume its an array.  using tables[] accesses the next index of the array (where the data you want is stored) instead of the whole array (object) itself.

Answer (score 3):

Just an example of how to pass an array to server from html form

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <input name="tables[]" value="value1" />
    <input name="tables[]" value="value2" />
    ....
</form>
```

**PHP** (codeigniter)

```
$tables_array=$this->input->post('tables'); // an array with all values of tables[] input/item of form
```

if you `print_r($tables_array);` then the output will be

```
Array ( [0] => value1 [1] => value2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with CodeIgniter, but the basic solution you're looking for is either to make an array and pass that (if CodeIgniter has a function for passing an array in POST that would be best, otherwise make a function that appends the values and delimits them with a comma or semicolon and another function to interpret that on the other end) or to pass, say "tables1:14", "tables2:15", "tables3:16" and then process them once you receive them. I think the array would probably be the best way, personally, but you may have a reason to use the second method.